# A Couple Android Soft Keyboard Questions

Tags: android, user-interface, soft-keyboard

This is kind of a repost, and I apologize for any broken rules, but I have a couple of questions about the soft keyboard on Android phones:

1)  I have an Android app with a couple different views (that the user switches between). How can I determine which is the current view??  I need to get the current view to execute the code that hides the virtual keyboard.

2)  How can I check whether the virtual keyboard is currently being displayed (so I can filter the actions of my various hard keys)??

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 0):

1)
public class ViewIdentification extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener{

```
EditText _edt1;
EditText _edt2;
EditText _edt3;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    _edt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(ViewIdentification.this);
    _edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
    _edt2.setOnFocusChangeListener(ViewIdentification.this);
    _edt3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText03);    
    _edt3.setOnFocusChangeListener(ViewIdentification.this);


}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       if(v == _edt1 && hasFocus == true){

        Toast.makeText(ViewIdentification.this, "The First EditText is focused now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }else if(v == _edt2 && hasFocus == true){

        Toast.makeText(ViewIdentification.this, "The Second EditText is focused now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }else if(v == _edt3 && hasFocus == true){

        Toast.makeText(ViewIdentification.this, "The Third EditText is focused now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

}
```

}

NOTE : In this way we can get to know which view is focused .

2)

This can be done by calculating the size of the activity ( the location at which the last focused view is at ) .